# RDLC table issue

Tags: rdlc

I am using RDLC report, I have two column and a single row in a table. Both columns are inside my table header tag.On first page design looks perfect but as the table extends to the next page the first column content shifted to the left and some portion got hide 
Similarly if we further extend the table to next pages the whole content get shifted to left and the area looks blank there. Refer the picture:

[image]

I am unable to get the reson behind this plz help me.

Comment: This also happened when you export your report to PDF?

Comment: I am not creating report ,i am generating pdf directly from web form .